# How to know when a button is clicked in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button

Pls I need your help in some cases about button in C#. How can I know when a particular button is clicked. I want to use the if condition statement to write the event. So I want it to do something when particular button is clicked. I want to put all the code inside one function or class then I can call it anytime. For example

```
private void showPanel()  
{  
    if (dashPanelButton.Clicked == true)  
    {  
        dashPanel.Visible = true;  
    }  
    else if(studInfoBtn.Clicked == true)  
    {  
        studInfoPanel.Visible = true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        homePanel.Visible = true; 
    }
}
```

Note the above code is just an assumption not really a working code. Just using it to explain myself

Answer (score 2):

You don't "check if a button is clicked".  The code isn't going to just sit around and wait for that click to happen.  Instead, you "respond to a button click" with a click event handler:

```
void myButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something when the button is clicked
}
```

You can attach the handler to the button in the designer, or in code:

```
myButton.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_Click);
```

Now, if you want the same handler to be used for *multiple* buttons, that's where that `Object sender` becomes useful.  That's a reference to the object which raised the event.  So in your case, it would be the button which was clicked:

```
void myButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var theButton = (Button)sender;
    // now "theButton" is the button which was clicked
}
```

Comment: What I mean is i want to create a method "showPanel()" that will show a particular panel when a particular button is clicked. Then I call the showPanel method in the each button event. So that whenever a button is clicked, it calls the showPanel method and the showPanel method will check which button is clicked and then show a particular Panel. Thanks

Comment: @OyetokeTobiEmmanuel: In that case it sounds like you'd pass `sender` to the `showPanel` method.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: @OyetokeTobiEmmanuel: Declare it in the method signature: `private void showPanel(Button clickedButton)`  Then when you call that method, you'd pass the `sender` object that's been cast to a `Button` (as it is in the answer here).

Answer (score 0):

Register the button `Click` event and do whatever you want in the event handler like

```
dashPanelButton.Click += new EventHandler(myhandler);

protected void myhandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want, like this:

```
private void showPanel(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == dashPanelButton)
        {
            dashPanel.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (sender == studInfoBtn)
        {
            studInfoBtn.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            homePanel.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

make sure your button is wired correctly

```
dashPanelButton.Click += new EventHandler(showPanel);
studInfoBtn.Click += new EventHandler(showPanel);
```