# Check if a button was pressed within another button

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't seem to figure out how to check if a button is clicked after a button has been clicked.

Inside of my `addBtn_Click` function, I am wanting to see if the user clicks on the `editBtn` that now contains the text "Cancel". However, I saw that if I wanted to use the same handler to be used for multiple buttons I would be able to use it as shown `editBn == (Button)sender`. ([How to know when a button is clicked in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666087/how-to-know-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-c-sharp)). However, whenever I do this, the program does not enter the `if` statement. What am I doing wrong?

```cs
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    productIDTextBox.Enabled = false;
    searchGroupBox.Enabled = false;
    addBtn.Text = "Save";
    editBtn.Text = "Cancel";
    deleteBtn.Enabled = false;
    exitBtn.Enabled = false;

    if(editBtn == (Button)sender)
    {
        productIDTextBox.Enabled = true;
        searchGroupBox.Enabled = true;
        addBtn.Text = "Add";
        editBtn.Text = "Edit";
        deleteBtn.Enabled = true;
        exitBtn.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another approach, do not change single button text and behaviour, but create separate buttons for every functionality and show/hide them based on the some logic

Comment: You'd be better off having different buttons that you hide and show rather than the same button that you edit the text/intent of

Comment: As the others said, your issues comes down to trying to have multiple-functional buttons. That being said, you can access the button raising the event. Just Cast the sender to Button, at wich point you could check what it's text is.